# k-way merge sort base case

Tags: algorithm, sorting

i don't understand this particular sample code from geeksforgeeks on k-way merge sort.
More specifically, I don't understand what the "n" in the for loop in the base case for divide() is. Is it the number of students in each array? (which in this case is 4)

Also could you please explain what the for loop in divide() is doing in relation to the divide() process? + what is the base case (l==r) supposed to mean?

Thank you.

> Approach: The idea becomes clear once we start looking at the k arrays as the intermediate state of the merge sort algorithm.
> Since there are k arrays that are already sorted, merge the k arrays. Create a recursive function which will take k arrays and divide them into two parts and call the function recursively with each half. The base cases are when the value of k is less than 3.
> See this article to merge two arrays in O(n) time.

> Algorithm: Initialize the output array with the size N*k.
> Call the function divide. Let l and r represent the range of arrays that are to be merged and thus vary between 0 to k-1.
> At each step, we call the left and right half of the range recursively so that, they will be sorted and stored in the output array.
> After that, we merge the left and right half. For merging, we need to determine the range of indexes for the left and right halves in the output array. We can easily find that.
> Left part will start from the index l * n of the output array.
> Similarly, right part will start from the index ((l + r) / 2 + 1) * n of the output array.

```
import java.util.*; 
  
class GFG { 
  
    static int n = 4; 
  
    // Function to perform 
    // merge operation 
    static void merge( 
        int l, int r, int[] output) 
    { 
        // To store the starting point 
        // of left and right array 
        int l_in = l * n, r_in 
                          = ((l + r) / 2 + 1) * n; 
  
        // to store the size of left and 
        // right array 
        int l_c = ((l + r) / 2 - l + 1) * n; 
        int r_c = (r - (l + r) / 2) * n; 
  
        // array to temporarily store left 
        // and right array 
        int l_arr[] = new int[l_c], 
            r_arr[] = new int[r_c]; 
  
        // storing data in left array 
        for (int i = 0; i < l_c; i++) 
            l_arr[i] = output[l_in + i]; 
  
        // storing data in right array 
        for (int i = 0; i < r_c; i++) 
            r_arr[i] = output[r_in + i]; 
  
        // to store the current index of 
        // temporary left and right array 
        int l_curr = 0, r_curr = 0; 
  
        // to store the current index 
        // for output array 
        int in = l_in; 
  
        // two pointer merge for two sorted arrays 
        while (l_curr + r_curr < l_c + r_c) { 
            if ( 
                r_curr == r_c 
                || (l_curr != l_c 
                    && l_arr[l_curr] < r_arr[r_curr])) { 
                output[in] = l_arr[l_curr]; 
                l_curr++; 
                in++; 
            } 
            else { 
                output[in] = r_arr[r_curr]; 
                r_curr++; 
                in++; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
  
    // Code to drive merge-sort and 
    // create recursion tree 
    static void divide(int l, int r, int[] output, 
                       int arr[][]) 
    { 
        if (l == r) { 
  
            /* base step to initialize the output  
        array before performing merge  
        operation */
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                output[l * n + i] = arr[l][i]; 
  
            return; 
        } 
  
        // to sort left half 
        divide(l, (l + r) / 2, output, arr); 
  
        // to sort right half 
        divide((l + r) / 2 + 1, r, output, arr); 
  
        // merge the left and right half 
        merge(l, r, output); 
    } 
  
    // Driver Code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // input 2D-array 
        int arr[][] = { { 5, 7, 15, 18 }, 
                        { 1, 8, 9, 17 }, 
                        { 1, 4, 7, 7 } }; 
  
        // Number of arrays 
        int k = arr.length; 
  
        // Output array 
        int[] output = new int[n * k]; 
  
        divide(0, k - 1, output, arr); 
  
        // Print merged array 
        for (int i = 0; i < n * k; i++) 
            System.out.print(output[i] + " "); 
    } 
}
```

from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-k-sorted-arrays-set-3-using-divide-and-conquer-approach/?ref=rp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an advanced version of `merge sort`. Here is the scenario, we have `k` sorted arrays with `n` elements (as you called them students) in each. The goal is to have a single sorted array (`output`) of all the elements which is the size of `k*n`. Since the `k` arrays are sorted we just need an algorithm to merge them. To do so, in a recursive function `divide(l, r, output, arr)`, we divide `l-th` to `r-th` arrays into two sets and recursively call *divide* for them. For example, for `k=3` we have `l=0` and `r=2`. In the *divide* function since `l!=r` we skip the first if and we call two functions `divide(0, 1, output, arr)` and `divide(2, 2, output, arr)`. Again, in the first function call, we call `divide(0, 0, output, arr)` and `divide(1, 1, output, arr)`. Now, when we have `l==r` we should save the **l-th (equal to r-th)** array to output *(Note that the the `merge` function is an in place function)*. To do so, remember for converting a `2d` array `A[n][m]` to a `1d` array `B[n*m]` we can access to `A[i][j]` with `B[i*n+j]`. For more clarification, I put some prints in *divide* function:

```
static void divide(int l, int r, int[] output, 
    int arr[][]) 
    { 
        if (l == r) { 
  
            /* base step to initialize the output  
                array before performing merge  
                operation */
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                output[l * n + i] = arr[l][i]; 

            System.out.println("After writing to output:");
            for (int i = 0; i < n * k; i++) 
                System.out.print(output[i] + " ");
            System.out.println()
            return; 
        } 
  
        // to sort left half 
        divide(l, (l + r) / 2, output, arr); 
  
        // to sort right half 
        divide((l + r) / 2 + 1, r, output, arr); 
  
        // merge the left and right half 
        merge(l, r, output);
        System.out.print("After Merge:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n * k; i++) 
                System.out.print(output[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
```

and here is the output:

```
After writing to output:
[5, 7, 15, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  # after divide(0, 0, output, arr)
After writing to output:
[5, 7, 15, 18, 1, 8, 9, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0] # after divide(1, 1, output, arr)
After Merge:
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 17, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0] # after merge(0, 1, output)
After writing to output:
[1, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 17, 18, 1, 4, 7, 7] # after divide(2, 2, output, arr)
After Merge:
[1, 1, 4, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 15, 17, 18] # after merge(0, 2, output)
```